# ExtJS infinite loop on grid focus

Tags: infinite-loop, extjs4.2, gridpanel

We're using ExtJS 4.2 and ran into weird problem.
There's a grouped grid panel from which we drag elements to a tree panel. In most cases everything is working fine, but sometimes for unknown reason wrong item is dragged or it doesn't happen at all. In these cases call stack that's printed in console shows infinite loop:

```
Ext.dom.Query.Ext.core.DomQuery.Ext.DomQuery.DQ.filter
Ext.dom.Query.Ext.core.DomQuery.Ext.DomQuery.DQ.is
Ext.define.is
Ext.define.getNode
Ext.define.indexOf
Ext.define.onLastFocusChanged
Ext.define.setLastFocused
Ext.define.focusRow
Ext.define.onRowFocusExt.define.onLastFocusChanged
Ext.define.setLastFocused
Ext.define.focusRow
Ext.define.onRowFocus
....
Ext.define.onLastFocusChanged
Ext.define.setLastFocused
Ext.define.focusRow
Ext.define.onRowFocus
....
```

Any attempts to deliberatelly replicate the bug had failed, and logging all information on grid events to console doesn't show anything unusual.

Has anybody had this problem, and maybe fixed it successfully?

Thanks

Comment: Also ran into this problem

Comment: how did you implement drag and drop feature. could you add the code snippet to understand what you did?

Comment: I have the same problem, its driving me crazy